# customize debian live user

Tags: debian, deb, debian-based, squashfs

how can I change the home folder of default live user in a customized debian linux? what I want is:

1. installing some packages in default installation and for live boot of debian
2. some customization in home folder of any new user and the live default user

I know I can remaster a debian and install my package and change what I whant but what about the default user. is it influenced by my default user changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when a new Linux user is created, the `/etc/skel` directory and its contents are copied over to create the new user's home directory.  Permissions stay the same, ownership is changed to the new user and their primary group.

In some cases, the default directories for a desktop environment - `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, `~/Downloads`, etc. are NOT in `/etc/skel` and instead are created if they do not exist when a user first logs in to a desktop environment session.

Comment: thanks dear for your response. which script done making of `~/Download` and etc in the new home folder?

Comment: The desktop environment - gnome, mate, whatever - will do it if it needs/expects those directories to be there and they don't exist when a session is started.  Or if you want to pre-populate it (ie, short cuts on the desktop, perhaps a directory full of files, etc) then you can go ahead and put it in `/etc/skel` as well.